# Pass Java .class file to Delphi Constructor

Tags: java, android, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm working with JNI to access Android functions in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. I need to pass a `.class` type as an argument for a Delphi function constructor.

The original Java method looks like this:

```
private Intent getServiceIntent() {
    return new Intent(this, ToyVpnService.class);
}
```

From the Android Documentation for the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) constructor:

> ```
> Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
> ```
>
> Create an intent for a specific component.

I have to use this constructor, I can't change it.

I need to translate this to Delphi, but I am stuck at passing the `.class` type.
Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
function TForm1.GetServiceIntent: JIntent;
begin
  result := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(FContext, ???);
end;
```

I tried to use the ClassLoader from Java, but can't access the `loadClass()` function because it is protected so package only.

I tried to use `Class.forName`, but can't specify the `Path` from the `.class`  file.

I added the `.class` file as a Delphi resource file and loaded it via `TResourceStream`, but couldn't find a solution to convert this input to a Java `Class` reference.

Comment: My first question is why you need the java class file in a Delphi program?

Comment: @rabbit, [FireMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey).

Comment: Because the constructor of JIntent requieres this.
From Java Doc:
 "Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)

Create an intent for a specific component. "
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

And i have to use this method, and can't change it.

Comment: `ToyVpnService.class` is not a reference to the Java `.class` file, it is a reference to the Java *class*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34613627/80901), I guess it should be something like

```
Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(SharedActivityContext,
  TJLang_Class.JavaClass.forName(StringToJString('com.example.ToyVpnService'),
  True, SharedActivity.getClassLoader));
```